# scrapy callback to crawl paginated pages

Tags: pagination, scrapy

I have written a spider to crawl a website. 
I am able to generate all the page urls (pagination).
I need help to crawl all these pages and and then print the response.

url_string="http://website.com/ct-50658/page-"

```
class SpiderName(Spider):
    name="website"
    allowed_domains=["website.com"]
    start_urls=["http://website.com/page-2"]

def printer(self, response):
    hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    x=hxs.select("//span/a/@title").extract()
    with open('website.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for i in x:
            spamwriter.writerow(i)


def parse(self,response):
    hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    #sel=Selector(response)
    pages=hxs.select("//div[@id='srchpagination']/a/@href").extract()
    total_pages=int(pages[-2][-2:])
    j=0
    url_list=[]
    while (j<total_pages):
        j=j+1
        urls=url_string+str(j)  
        url_list.append(urls)
    for one_url in url_list:
        request= Request(one_url, callback=self.printer)
    return request
```

Comment: You're recreating the 'website.csv' file for every `one_url` response. You should create it once (in `__init__` for example) and save a CSV Writer reference to it in an attribute of your spider, referencing something like `self.csvwriter` in `def printer`. Also, in `for one_url in url_list:` you should use `yield Request(one_url, callback=self.printer)`. Here, you're returning only the last Request

Comment: can you please explain in a bit detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're recreating the 'website.csv' file for every `one_url` Request's response. You should probably create it once (in `__init__` for example) and save a CSV Writer reference to it in an attribute of your spider, referencing something like self.csvwriter in def printer.

Also, in `for one_url in url_list:`loop, you should use `yield Request(one_url, callback=self.printer)`. Here, you're returning only the last Request

Here's a sample spider with these modifications and some code simplifications:

```
class SpiderName(Spider):
    name="website"
    allowed_domains=["website.com"]
    start_urls=["http://website.com/page-2"]

    def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpiderName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.spamwriter = csv.writer(open('website.csv', 'wb'),
                                     delimiter=' ',
                                     quotechar='|',
                                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    def printer(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for i in hxs.select("//span/a/@title").extract():
            self.spamwriter.writerow(i)

    def parse(self,response):
        hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        #sel=Selector(response)
        pages = hxs.select("//div[@id='srchpagination']/a/@href").extract()
        total_pages = int(pages[-2][-2:])
        while j in range(0, total_pages):
            yield Request(url_string+str(j), callback=self.printer)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Paul. Works for me. this is exactly where i was stuck